# I want to copy files, listed in a .txt file, into a new folder

Tags: batch-file, copy

I have roughly 2000 documents in one folder and I want to seperate them into different folders. 
I have created a "documents.txt", which lists every file I´m interested in.

The .txt file reads as:

```
C:\Users\NIE\Desktop\test2\one.pdf
C:\Users\NIE\Desktop\test2\two.pdf
C:\Users\NIE\Desktop\test2\three.pdf
```

So now I went on creating a .bat file:

```
@echo off 
FOR /F "delims=" %a IN (C:\Users\...\Desktop\test2\documents.txt) DO COPY "%%~a" "C:\Users\...\Desktop\test2\kopieren\%%~nxa"
```

The folder structure is like:

In "...\Desktop\test2", all documents are located. In a subfolder ("...\Desktop\test2\copy"), the specific documents (as listed in the documents.txt) should be copied.

While running my code, I´m getting the statement:

```
%C:\Users\...\Desktop\test2\one.pdf
The syntax for the filename, path is wrong
       0 files were copied.
```

So I guess the "%" seems to be the bad guy here. I tried different styles for the .txt file, like

```
one.pdf
userprofile%\Desktop\test2\one.pdf   (thought I could use the first % for completing the "%userprofile%" stuff
```

Every solution I could find via google did not worked either, the formatting of the .txt file seems to be a problem in my case.

Really looking forward for you answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have done a fatal mistake: `%a`
Fixed:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN (C:\Users\...\Desktop\test2\documents.txt) DO COPY "%%~a" "C:\Users\...\Desktop\test2\kopieren\%%~nxa"
```

Comment: Well, that´s kinda embarassing :(  As soon as I changed something, I first tested it directly in cmd, and not via .bat file. So I deleted the second %, because cmd can´t handle two. I just tried it with `%%a`in a bat file and it works. Thank you!